# Can I make Google Analytics see some pages as equal?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-php-client

I am currently using the Google Analytics API to get information about visits to my web site. One thing I notice is that in some cases I get two different results for the same page because the way the user accessed them was different. For example, I get separate results like this:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage - 500 pageviews
http://example.com/mypage - 500 pageviews
```

What I want is for them to be considered the same so the result I get back is consolidated like so:

```
http://example.com/mypage - 1000 pageviews
```

Is this possible using PHP client code to access the API? My current code includes these lines:

```
filter = 'pageviews > 100 && pagePath !~ ^\/$';
$ga_month->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, array('hostname', 'pagePath'), array('pageviews'), '-pageviews', $filter, $start_date_month, $end_date);
```

I've seen this code for using search and replace functions to combine results in the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters), but I don't know how to integrate the following JSON request into the PHP code above:

```
  "searchAndReplaceDetails": {
    "field": string,
    "searchString": string,
    "replaceString": string,
    "caseSensitive": boolean
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use search and replace filters and this resource (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en) tells you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The link you provided seems to be broken. I get a header graphic, but no content on the page.

Comment: Thank you, that does work in the analytics interface. However, in the question I'm asking about how do to this through the API. Is there a way to consolidate these results when querying the API from PHP?

Comment: This is for the Management API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters, search for "searchAndReplaceDetails". Which API are you using?

Comment: Please see my updated question with code. I'm using the PHP. I see in the page you linked that there is a JSON string for making a search and replace request, but I'm not sure how to integrate it with the code I have.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm not familiar with the implementation through PHP, but this link gives you some code examples, which includes PHP: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/insert